# Rotate and Zoom a group of tiles

Tags: xna, sprites, monogame, scale, rotate

I'm working on a tile-based game and I'm trying to rotate my tiles as a group around the center of the screen and want to have the ability to zoom in and out. Here my code:

```
        Matrix transform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-origin.X, -origin.Y, 0f)) *
                           Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotation) *
                           Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(zoomFactor, zoomFactor, 0)) *
                           Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(Basic.width, Basic.height, 0));

        Vector2 pos = new Vector2(r.X, r.Y);
        pos = Vector2.Transform(pos, transform);
        r.X = (int)pos.X;
        r.Y = (int)pos.Y;
        angle += rotation;

        Draw(r, origin, angle, zoomFactor, Color.White);
```

Somehow, this rotates my tiles around the lower right corner of the screen. The zooming point is also there.

When setting the second CreateTranslation to

```
        Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(origin.X, origin.Y, 0))
```

only 1/4 of the screen is visible.

Can someone help me with this? I just want to let the tiles rotate as a group around the center of the screen. Zomming should also be centered. How to achieve this without using a 2D camera?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your `transform` matrix to the `_spriteBatch.Begin()` method.

The following code provides the default parameters.

```
_spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred,null,null,null,null,null,transform);
```

Note that this only applies to drawing, and any collision code will need to be adjusted accordingly.